# Declaring a Swift Character type that could hold only ASCII characters?

Tags: swift, encoding, character

Swift's `Character` data type is a very broad set and I have a use case where I need to declare a variable which can only hold ascii characters. The type should not be able to accept characters outside ascii.

Do we have any other in built data types that are suitable for my use case?

Or do I need to write a custom solution?

If it requires custom solution what are the best possible ways to achieve it?

Comment: There is no type which holds only ASCII *characters.* What about `UInt8` to store ASCII *codes?*

Comment: I could use UInt8, but I would loose the goodness of typing literal characters. I now get that it will need some custom solution. Do you think ExpressibleByStringLiteral would help me create a custom data type?

Comment: One problem is that there is (as far as I know) no way to make the *compiler* check for a valid ASCII literal, i.e. on `let a: MyASCIIChar = ""`, that could only throw a runtime exception. –   You might also be interested in https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0243-codepoint-and-character-literals.md (which was rejected).

Comment: Lets say I implement a custom type conforming to ExpressibleByStringLiteral. I thought of checking if its in the ascii range and returning nil if its not ascii. There is a problem though the initializer declared by ExpressibleByStringLiteral is not optional and its a dead end.

Comment: Exactly. All  those `init(xxxLiteral:)` initializers are not failable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the question comments, it seems it's not possible to have a check on compile time.

---

A runtime solution could be:

You can check if a `Character` is Ascii by `<#Character#>.isASCII`, then you can create a custom class that only stores a value if the condition is satisfied.

```swift
struct CustomASCIIClass {

    private var storedValue : Character? = nil

    var value : Character? {
        get {
            return self.storedValue ?? nil
        }

        set (newValue) {
            if (newValue?.isASCII ?? false) {
                self.storedValue = newValue
            } else {
                // handle not possible value, throw something or make the variable to have nil value.
                print("invalid: ", newValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
var a = CustomASCIIClass()
a.value = Character("A")
print(a.value) // Optional("A")

var b = CustomASCIIClass()
b.value = Character("")
print(b.value) // nil
```

Comment: `Character` already has a  `isASCII` property (at least in the latest Swift version), so there is no need to iterate over the `unicodeScalars`.

Comment: It is a nice approach, but we are not able to use literal assignments in this solution.

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht I will instead accept this answer. I think I am sure now that we can't do it with literals. Literals are implicitly non optionals, and I can't have an optional initializer for something expressible by literals. Please do confirm If I am correct.

Comment: @RohanBhale can you rephrase that please? As far as I understood and know, yes.

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht to rephrase: Literals are implicitly non optionals(well they are literals because they are expressed literally and hence non optionals) and I can't have an optional initializer for something expressible by literals.


Lets say let myChar: MyCustomChar = "¾". If It had been possible then this would initialized non optional MyCustomChar as nil. Or we could say some one can only use it if they declare variable as optional.

Comment: Yes, only optional variables can have nil as value.